# Why is the signature part of a jwt token always different, even when created with the same values?

Tags: node.js, jwt

[jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), v8.5.0
node v10.13.0
npm 6.4.1

If i create a token several times with:

```
jwt.sign({ user_email: user_email, user_id: user_id, username: username }, 'RESTFULAPIs')
```

---

*Question 01:*

It seems the first 2 parts of the string are always the same (the base64 encoded `header` and `payload` values), but the third part (the `signature`) is different.

Why is the `signature` different when the original values are the same?

*What I've Tried:*

I have read the `signature` section at [jwt.io/introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> To create the signature part you have to take:
>
> - the encoded header
> - the encoded payload
> - a secret
> - the algorithm specified in the header
>
> and sign that.

So, as a guess:

Is the `signature` the result of encrypting the base64 encoded `header` and `payload` values using the `HS256` algorithm and `secret`, which in this case is the string `RESTFULAPIs`, which produces a different *result* each time it is encrypted, whilst the decoded result is always the same?

---

*Question 02:*

The decoded value of the different tokens is always the same, except for an object property called `iat`.  What does that property represent?

```js
{
iat: 1561358034
user_id: "25423537fshsdgA"
user_email: "info@test.com"
username: "bob"
}

{
iat: 1561358156
user_id: "25423537fshsdgA"
user_email: "info@test.com"
username: "bob"
}
```

Actually, after researching this second question more, I came across this:

> The "iat" (issued at) claim identifies the time at which the JWT was
> issued. This claim can be used to determine the age of the JWT. Its
> value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value.

Source:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6

Comment: so you answered question 2 already, right? When the IAT changes, it means the payload changes and different payload leads to a different signature. Btw., the signature is not "result of encrypting the base64 encoded header and payload values". The signature is a hash over heaer and payload.

Comment: Actually, your observation regarding the different IAT makes the whole question invalid, because we're not talking about "the same values" anymore, your input might be the same, but IAT, which is added automatically, makes it different each time.

Comment: Interesting insight about the `payload` changing due to the automatically added `iat`, i hadn't thought of that, however i have just double checked - when generating multiple tokens with the same header and payload (excluding the `iat` property that i assume `jwt` adds automatically when using `jwt.sign()`), the first two parts of all the tokens are the same (the encoded `header` and `payload`), whereas the third part is different (the `signature`).

Comment: what do you mean by "excluding the iat property"? You got a token without iat? Then please update your question above and show us two tokens with identical header and payload but different signature.

Comment: Actually, I think you were right, on closer inspection the first two parts of all the tokens i was generating *were* different by 3 characters (in 188 characters)!  So your answer that the payloads were different, due to the automatically assigned `iat` property, which was causing the signature to be different, seems to be correct.

Answer (score 10):

Per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken):

> Generated jwts will include an `iat` (issued at) claim by default unless
>   `noTimestamp` is specified. If `iat` is inserted in the payload, it will
>   be used instead of the real timestamp for calculating other things
>   like `exp` given a timespan in `options.expiresIn`.

So, you could test generating multiple jwts in the same second (which would therefore have the same `iat`) and verify that the signature is the same.  Or, use the `noTimestamp` option, which would eliminate the `iat` and therefore make the payloads identical.  I don't think this is the recommended way to do it.

But in short, `iat` is "issued at" as you've answered yourself, and the payload (and therefore the signature) is going to change every second as the inserted `iat` changes, per the docs I've quoted for you.

Comment: So, does the existence of the `iat` during the jwt generation allows us to have the different token validity period durations (e.g. a token which is valid just for an hour)?

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov - sort of, but that's really what the `exp` claim is for. The `iat` claim should be used to determine the age of the token, and `exp` for its validity (see also `nbf`) - the RFC is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-9

Comment: Got it. Thank you.